# Compiler calling base class method instead of children one

Tags: c++, inheritance

First sorry for the code being in a foreign language.

Im having a problem, when I compile the code below the compiler calls the base method instead of the child one.

I have this base class :

Jugador.h

```
#ifndef JUGADOR_H_
#define JUGADOR_H_

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Jugador{
    protected:
        bool color;//true->rojo   false-> azul
    public:
        Jugador(bool rojo) { color = rojo; }
        Jugador() {}
        virtual string getInput();
        ~Jugador(){}
};

#endif
```

Jugador.cpp

```
#include "Jugador.h"
using namespace std;
string Jugador::getInput(){
cout<<"Is Called"<<endl;
}
```

And this child class:
JugadorHumano.h

```
#ifndef JUGADORHUMANO_H_
#define JUGADORHUMANO_H_
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Jugador.h"

using namespace std;

class JugadorHumano: public Jugador {
    public:
        JugadorHumano(bool rojo) :Jugador(rojo) {}
        virtual string getInput();//Tested with override too
};

#endif
```

JugadorHumano.cpp

```
#include "JugadorHumano.h"
using namespace std;

string JugadorHumano::getInput(){
    string input;
    getline(cin, input);
    return input;
}
```

Then, on a third class method unrelated to those two outside using them I have made:

```
Jugador rojo;
rojo=JugadorHumano(true);
rojo.getInput();
```

Thanks for your attention.

Edit: Sorry, this is my first question, added the cpp files

Edit2: Made the changes sugested by @Raindrop7 , now compiles but still calls base method, it prints "Is Called" instead of doing the getline.

Edit3:Thanks

OLD:When the compiler arrives to getInput it throws an error "Reference to 'Jugador::getInput()' is undefined". I'm not sure why this happens nor a way to fix it.

Comment: Look up object slicing

Comment: Please review [MCVE].  Your snippet has neither getinput() method implementation, so yes, the linker can not find it.

Comment: where did you define Jugador::getInput() ??

Comment: remove the word override and define your member functions GetInput() and include string in header files where string is used

Comment: @HAG My intention was not to define It, It is only used on the children classes

Comment: @Signum then make it pure -> virtual string getInput()=0; and you will not be able to instantiate Jugador ...

Comment: Tried to do that and used a pointer to access 
`Jugador * rojo;
JugadorHumano jug=JugadorHumano(true);
rojo= &jug;
rojo->getInput();`
It still told me I was calling the base method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If don't want to define getInput() in your base class (Jugador), as per your comments, then you need to make it pure virtual

```
virtual string getInput()=0;
```

However, you will not be able to instantiate Jugador since it will become an abstract class,

```
Jugador rojo; // error tries to instantiate abstract class
```

Thus, in your third class you need to create JugadorHumano object

```
Jugador * rojo = new JugadorHumano(true);
rojo->getInput();
```

Comment: Tried something similar `Jugador * rojo; JugadorHumano jug=JugadorHumano(true); rojo= &jug; rojo->getInput();`
A roundabout way , the compiler still tries to call the base method and throws an error of it being abstract.

Comment: Ok, I managed to make it work with your suggestions (I didn't make it pure virtual as I'll need some concrete things latter). So, if i dont do pointer = new ObjectConstructor and, instead i get the reference from an already made Object it tries to point to the base method instead of the child one

Comment: @Signum I'm glad that you sorted it out. Sorry I'm not totally sure why the other code that you have in your comment doesn't work .. May be consider asking another question with more details.